# How to Synchronize the DB from Index Using Elasticsearch

Tags: java, mysql, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-jdbc-river

I have an use case where an Elasticsearch index and a MySQL Database should be remain synchronized and meet the following conditions.

1) Whenever I insert/update/delete in Elasticsearch index it should be synchronized with the Database(MySQL).

2) This synchronization should be done instantly.

3) For the Elasticsearch Index I am doing insert/update/delete at any time with any number of requests.

How can I do this using Elasticsearch?

Thanks!!

Comment: Shouldn't it be the other way around ? You put the data into MySql and then index it into ES ?

Comment: In my use case I have the above set of method. So the other way is not possible

Comment: That is a pity, because MySQL is (nearly) ACID while ElasticSearch is not. It really should be the other way around.

Comment: Did you check this - https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/blob/master/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/index/indexing/IndexingOperationListener.java , this is a listener which gets invoked once the index gets updated , see if you can override the postIndex method and then sync up the MySql DB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this out - [Listener for ES](https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/blob/master/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/index/indexing/IndexingOperationListener.java)

So this is essentially a listener which gets invoked when the index gets updated / deleted . So override the method postCreate ,postIndex and postDelete and accordingly update the MySQl DB

Comment: Thank you for you answer Rocky.Let me try this

Comment: Hi Rocky. Do we want to create any River for this to do the sync?

Comment: AFAIK River is used for data flowing into ES , in your case its the other way around , so I doubt if River would be of any help here